# How can I loop thru an indexed array in Handlerbars.js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I've an indexed array. How can I loop thru it using Handlebars?
I'm using #each /each for loop but to which variable is the value assigned inside the block.

My data loops like this.

```
{
            id: "12424",
            title: "Chit Chat with Kimberly Bauer",
            description: "Discuss about what's going to happen to Jack Bauer in Season 9 of 24",
            from: "12/16/2012 9:00am EST",
            to: "12/16/2012 10:00am EST",
            duration: "1:00 hr",
            invitees: [
                "kim@24.com",
                "jack@24.com",
                "nina@24.com",
                "tony@24.com",
                "all@no.one"
            ]
        }
```

I want to display all the invitees.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.
It is assigned to . (dot)

It can be used as `{{.}}`

Comment: or for more clarity you can use `{{this}}`

Comment: Or, better yet, assign the value to a variable i.e. {{#each invitee in invitees}} and access it using {{invitee}}